# Eclipse and/or node.exe using 100% CPU

Tags: java, eclipse, node.js, cpu-usage

OK, this is driving me insane! It used to be infrequent and now its practically ever character I type that causes Eclipse goes into 'Not Responding' and CPU rockets towards 100% and stays there for a minute. Sometimes this is accompanied by node.exe taking half the CPU and a LOT of memory. I kill node.exe and sometimes it stays off but mostly it comes back.

I've looked up node.exe and can't figure out what it has to do with my application. I'm writing a webapp using Tomcat, Struts, Java, JSP, JQuery. I disabled every plugin from Preferences->startup/shutdown with no effect.

Help! I can't develop when every keypress takes a minute!

Comment: I think Node.exe is a virus (if you aren't developing in node.js, that is)... I'd try to fix that up, because it's definitely not Eclipse it seems in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442049 or https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/159

[image]

I overcomed by removing `<nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>`

But you may have other JSDT related issue.

**And you must know exactly what process is consuming CPU at what rate.**

Answer (score -3):

I would really suggest not using Eclipse for node.  Try NotePad++ on Windows or Sublime or Atom or something...